# SlowCheetah transformations of QuartzNet config

Tags: xml, xpath, quartz.net, slowcheetah

I am trying to set up transformation, using *SlowCheetah*, of a QuartzNet job configuration file. QuartzNet requires the xmlns attribute to be present on the job-scheduling-data node, but the presence of this attribute seems to stop SlowCheetah from running the transformations.

Simplified, this is what my scheduling config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
<schedule>
<job>
  <name>Job1</name>
  <group>Group1</group>
  <description>Description</description>
  <job-type>MySample.MyJob, MySample</job-type>
</job>

<trigger>
  <cron>
    <name>DefaultTrigger</name>
    <job-name>Job1</job-name>
    <job-group>Group1</job-group>
    <cron-expression>0 0 4 * * ? *</cron-expression>
    <time-zone>GMT Standard Time</time-zone>
  </cron>
</trigger>
</schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

The config transformation looks like this:

```
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" >
<cron-expression xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(/job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron/cron-expression[../name/text() = 'DefaultTrigger'])">"##DAILY_SCHEDULE##</cron-expression>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

The transformation doesn't work unless I either remove

```
xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
```

from the original config file and the transformation file, or specify the namespace as, for example `xmlns:ns1`. The problem with either of these two approaches is that Quartz requires `xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"` to be present.

I have also tried using XPath expressions with `local-name()` in an effort to ignore the namespace in the expression syntax, but to no avail.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your XPath expression should be:

```
/job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron/cron-expression[../job-name/text() = 'Job1']
```

Since it was matching `name` and not `job-name`.

The scary namespace-ignoring XPath expression below should also work:

```
/*[local-name()='job-scheduling-data']/*[local-name()='schedule']/*[local-name()='trigger']/*[local-name()='cron']/*[local-name()='cron-expression'][../*[local-name()='job-name']/text() = 'Job1']
```

Comment: Hello. There is no node called 'job-name'?

Comment: There *is* one in the path you are using. Maybe you actually want `/job-scheduling-data/schedule/job`, where there *is* a `name` element and no `job-name`.

Comment: Or perhaps your *predicate* should compare using match the `name` which is child of the `job` element. If that's the case, it would be `/job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron/cron-expression[../../../job/name/text() = 'Job1']`

Comment: Sorry - I'm an idiot :-) I've updated the transformation XML now to correctly reflect that I'm matching on name, which is a child of cron. 

Anyway - I tried your suggested namespace-ignoring XPath expression, and it didn't work. But upon closer inspection, I had used different casing of words in the original XML and in my XPath expression... and that turned out to be the issue. Your namespace-ignoring expression _does_, in fact, work :-) Thank you!

Comment: @helderdarocha first XPath expression didn't work but the second(ignoring namespace) one worked.