# Transform XML Config of a Cron Job Time for different environments

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt

I'm trying to perform a transform of a cron job xml that i have.  But the transform doesn't work. I have tried all permutations but something is off..

here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.0">

  <processing-directives>
    <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
  </processing-directives>

  <schedule>
    <job>
      <name>Suspend User Job</name>
      <group>DailyJob</group>
      <description>This job will Suspend/Terminate User</description>
      <job-type>SuspendTerminateUserJob</job-type>
      <durable>true</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
    </job>

    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>suspendTerminateUserTrigger</name>
        <group>indexTriggerGroup</group>
        <job-name>Suspend User Job</job-name>
        <job-group>DailyJob</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>DoNothing</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0 55 3 ? * * *</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

trying to transform the CRON-EXPRESSION to a new time... using the following transform (note schedule/job... there can be many groupings so must search by the name of the trigger):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <schedule>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <add cron-expression="0 15 3 ? * * *" 
          xdt:Transform="Replace"
          xdt:Locator="XPath(job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron[name='suspendTerminateUserTrigger'])" />
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

Seems to me this xpath is correct.. but it doesn't transform the xml. i tried using the website https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/

Answer (score 1):

So the namespace of the original xml file was the issue. Solved this by 
**removing the namespace** from the original xml. And adding a Slash to the beginning of the xpath in the transform file.

```
xdt:Locator="XPath(/job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron[name='suspendTerminateUserTrigger'])" />
```

This could also be done by adding a namespace reference to transform file, and then in the xpath referring to each element with the name space.. but this seemed like a more convoluted approach. 
like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns:quartz="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData">
  <schedule>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <add cron-expression="0 15 3 ? * * *" 
          xdt:Transform="Replace"

          xdt:Locator="XPath(/quartz:job-scheduling-data/quartz:schedule/quartz:trigger/quartz:cron[quartz:name='suspendTerminateUserTrigger'])"
         />
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

EDIT: in the end I had to use the second approach to correctly implement the transforms.   To anyone reading this, please use that as the answer.

Comment: Did this end up working in practice? I found if I remove the namespace from the original file, then Quartz refuses to parse it when it starts up. So the transform process works, but the file is useless afterwards. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248270/slowcheetah-transformations-of-quartznet-config) about transforming a Quartz,NET jobs file also cites the same problem, but you appear to be saying that it wasn't an issue for you.

Comment: However the second approach with the namespace reference, did work nicely, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the second approach is actually what should be used.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think it would be worth editing your answer to clarify that, because currently it implies that either approach will work :-)